# What is the reason behind not using ReenterantLock inside put method of ConcurrentHashMap

Tags: java, hashmap

Below is the code snippet of Java 8 ConcurrentHashMap for put method

```
else if ((fh = f.hash) == MOVED)
    tab = helpTransfer(tab, f);
else {
    V oldVal = null;
    **synchronized (f) {**
    ...
}
```

Comment: Well, `synchronized` has (nowadays) some optimizations to avoid context switches "too easily", that could have certainly played a part in it. I.e. purely for performance reasons.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification **Kayaman**